# Can't do adjustment in clutch cable in motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, clutch-plate, hero-honda, clutch-cable

I installed a new clutch cable on my bike but after installation, its adjustment bolt was tighten at last. I don't understand why it is like that I can't adjust anymore in new cable. Please suggest me why I can't get the adjustment space in new clutch cable. It is a sign of worn out clutch plates. Please help me out.
Model hero Honda CBZ xtreme (2014)

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) you fitted it incorrectly or 2) the clutch cable was not the problem, so investigate further.

Comment: what type model are your bike,please edit more information into your question.is the cable too long or too short?.